# How to use dataType: 'jsonp' but still have application/json in Accept header?

Tags: jquery, json, http, jsonp

I want to access a REST service on another domain. If, in JQuery, I specify:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

it fails, as expected, since for cross-domain calls, JSONP must be used instead.

When I change this to:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

it is expected to work, but fails because the server expects `application/json` or `application/xml` or `text/html`, etc., but not `*/*`, sent by the JSONP request.

Is there a way to force JQuery to put `application/json` in `Accept` request header while doing a JSON request?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, because is the server that add the headers to the response not the client

Comment: @Jorge: sorry, my question was not explicit enough. I'm talking about the request headers, not the response headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK jQuery's implementation of JSONP uses a `<script>` tag that is injected into the DOM (thus the restriction to the GET verb only) for which you cannot control the `Accept` request content type header. The `src` of this `script` tag is simply pointed to the remote domain url. It is the browser that simply fetches the underlying endpoint sending a regular GET request.

So if you want to be able to set request headers for cross domain calls you will have to setup a server side script on your domain that will delegate the call to the remote domain (and set the respective headers) and then send the AJAX request to your script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to try something along these lines:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    }
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success : function(response) {
        ...
    }
})
```

Comment: I doubt that this will work, although I haven't tested it actually. jQuery uses a `<script>` tag for JSONP.

Comment: failing that you can always try adding:
contentType: 'application/json'

Comment: Sure, it's worth trying, it's just that my gut is telling me that it won't work.

Comment: Agreed, I have just tried a couple of other solutions, while it returns the data, it doesn't modify the Accepts headers. +1 your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be suitable for your use case, but when I have had to do cross-domain AJAX, I would typically just add an additional resource within my domain which would then call the external resource (via cURL or whatever) and return the value to the calling client.  In essence you are building a proxy for the AJAX call.  It is certainly more overhead, but you may be able to mitigate that by adding a caching layer for such calls.