# 405 (Method Not Allowed) while calling rest service via post

Tags: ajax, rest, post

Please help me solve this question, I tried everywhere else but dint find anything that could solve my issue.. I have simple rest service

```
  @POST
    @Path("/appointmentService")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Appointment saveAppointmentToDB(Appointment appointment)
    { 

    System.out.println("inAppointment");
    ObjectToDataBase otd = new ObjectToDataBase();
    Appointment appointmentSaved = (Appointment)otd.saveObjectToDatabase(appointment);
    return appointmentSaved;
}
```

I am trying to call this from Ajax query using following

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
            jQuery('form#add-new-task').bind('submit', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                var form = this;
                var json = ConvertFormToJSON(form);
                window.alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                var tbody = jQuery('#to-do-list > tbody');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/restProject/webresources/myresource/appointmentService',
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 

                });
```

but I am getting 405 method not found error..Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Note: It works fine when I call it from Postman tool.. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Are you doing a post request from postman or a get?

Comment: @Alegrowin Thanks for the quick response, I am doing post request from post man.

Comment: Try change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`. Have differences of this types.

Comment: Is this helping?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725591/how-to-use-datatype-jsonp-but-still-have-application-json-in-accept-header